# Count number of foreign key columns, ignore system tables, display against each tablename

Tags: sql, sql-server

We use foll. query **to count no. of primary key columns** in a database:-

```
SELECT t.name,is_primary_key
FROM sys.indexes i
INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON i.object_id = t.object_id AND 

t.type = 'U'
LEFT JOIN sys.extended_properties AS EP ON EP.major_id = T.

[object_id]
WHERE (EP.class_desc IS NULL 
OR (EP.class_desc <> 'OBJECT_OR_COLUMN'
    AND EP.[name] <> 'microsoft_database_tools_support'))
```

**It ignores the columns in system tables.**

Now we want to **query for the number of foreign keys** in the database. This **should ignore the system tables and display the count against each tablename**. Is this possible?

Below query returns all foreign keys in db, but I want to ignore the systabes.. Just like above query.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'FOREIGN_KEY_CONSTRAINT'
FROM sys.objects
WHERE type_desc IN ('FOREIGN_KEY_CONSTRAINT')
```

Comment: foreign keys or foreign key columns? I.e. do we have to deal with composite keys where the two answers will be different, and if so, which one is sought?

Comment: foreign key columns, consider an empty database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the below query. This will work for the required purpose:

```
SELECT KC.Column_Name, t.Table_Name, tc.Constraint_Name FROM information_schema.table_constraints tc
LEFT JOIN information_schema.tables t ON tc.Table_Name = t.Table_Name
LEFT JOIN information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE kc ON kc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY' AND TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
```

Comment: Try to create a new FK under sysdiagrams (under system table), then run above query and you will see that this FK appears in the result. If you do not have a table under systemtables in you management studio just right click on the 'database diagrams' and click on 'new database diagram', then hit cancel... Then you will see the sysdiagrams table under systemtables, now you can add new FK under this and run above query...

Comment: Hi, Refer to this link http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933204(v=sql.80).aspx
Information Schema provide an internal, system table-independent view of the SQL Server meta data.

Comment: Did u try to add the new FK under systemtables and check your query? Because when I do it still returns the FK from the systemtable sysdiargams

Comment: anyways for now I have added an 'AND' clause saying: and TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE 'sys%'

Answer (score 0):

This ?

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.COLUMN_NAME,
                B.CONSTRAINT_TYPE
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE A
       JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS B
         ON A.CONSTRAINT_NAME = B.CONSTRAINT_NAME
ORDER  BY CONSTRAINT_TYPE ASC
```

Use a where clause if needed

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
SELECT
K_Table = FK.TABLE_NAME,
FK_Column = CU.COLUMN_NAME,
PK_Table = PK.TABLE_NAME,
PK_Column = PT.COLUMN_NAME,
Constraint_Name = C.CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS C
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS FK ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = FK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS PK ON C.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = PK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE CU ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = CU.CONSTRAINT_NAME
INNER JOIN (
SELECT i1.TABLE_NAME, i2.COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS i1
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE i2 ON i1.CONSTRAINT_NAME = i2.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE i1.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
) PT ON PT.TABLE_NAME = PK.TABLE_NAME
```

[SOURCE](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2006/11/01/sql-server-query-to-display-foreign-key-relationships-and-name-of-the-constraint-for-each-table-in-database/)